# pysvn and tortoise subversion

Tags: pysvn

I must admit that I have extreme diffculties in using the pysvn module. Unlike other modules, this poses quite an amount of work and is unfortunately not like the python motto of batteries included.
I have a win 64 , windows 7 and running tortoise svn1.7.5. My python version is 2.7.2. Can anyone please explain me how can I do a simple import pysvn without getting an ImportError ?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I have a 64 bit machine, installing a 32 bit python27 instead of 64bit python2.7 solved the problem.